# How can I add different images for different buttons in Ionic when button clicked?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I managed to do it for a button but I cant figure out how to change the image when the other buttons are clicked. For example, when "4 Lados" or "2 Lados" is clicked than change the image to 4lados.png or 2lados.png but if "Full" button is clicked again changed it back to full.png.

HTML:

```
<div class="car-preview-holder">
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="3">
    <button class="img-holder" type="button" (click)="addEvent();">Full</button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="3">
    <button class="img-holder" type="button">4 Lados</button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="3">
    <button class="img-holder" type="button">2 Lados</button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="3">
    <button class="img-holder" type="button">Lite</button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

This is the default image shown before showing another image after button click.

```
<img class="preview ion-text-center" src="{{myimageFull}}" (click)="addEvent();">
```

TypeScript

```
declare public myimageFull = 'assets/imgs/vw.png';
addEvent(){
  this.myimageFull = 'assets/imgs/full.png';
  };
```

Comment: can you make stackblitz example.

Comment: Here it is: https://angular-ivy-awbs3s.stackblitz.io Thank you.